# Is it possible to log all incoming messages in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to know if it possible to configure logging for Apache Kafka broker to write all produced/consumed topics and it's messages.
I've been looking the log4j.properties but none of the suggested properties seems to do what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Looking the generated logging files by Kafka, none of them seems to log the messages written in the different topics.

UPDATE:
Not exactly what I was looking for, but for anyone looking something similar I found: https://github.com/kafka-lens/kafka-lens which provides a friendly GUI to view messages on different topics.

Comment: I'm interested; why do you want to log them? Is this for debug?

Comment: Yes, it's for debug. For example I need to see if a message to a topic has been published or not

Answer (score 2):

I feel like there's some confusion with the word "log".

As you're talking about log4j, I assume you're talking about what I'd call "application logs". Kafka does not write the records it handles in application/log4j logs. In Kafka, log4j logs are only used to trace errors and give some context about the work brokers are doing.

On the other hand, Kafka write/read records into/from its "[log](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#log)", the Kafka log. These are stored in the path specified by `log.dirs` (`/tmp/kafka-logs` by default) and are not directly readable. You can use the `DumpLogSegments` tool to read these files if you want, for example:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments \
    -f /tmp/kafka-logs/topic-0/00000000000000000000.log
```

Comment: Thanks Mickael, maybe I'm a bit confused. 
I have two applications one, that publish a message into a topic, and the other one that listens in that topic.
For example, if I need to debug if a message was effectively produced and sent into a topic, the only option that I have is to see if the producer application sent it. Is not possible for Kafka to log something like: received message: ... on topic: ... ?
Thanks again!

Comment: You won't find a message in the log4j logs but if you use the DumpLogSegments tool you can try to find your message in the Kafka logs